# $window.open not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

```
 alertPopup.then (function(res) {
      if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        $window.open('android_link_here', '_system')
      }

      else if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        $window.open('ios_link_here', '_system')
      }

      else {
        $window.open('other_link_here', '_system');
      }

    })
```

Hey Guys, I am trying to set up a popup that pops up informing the user when a new version of the application is available. What I want this to do is basically go to the page that i have in the string quotations. For iOS, this doesn't work and it fails to open up Safari and load the webpage I want it to. Note: I have not tested on Android yet as of this point.

It might be that I am doing something wrong but I looked around and no one seemed to have this problem.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular(2+)?

Comment: AngularJS is what I am currently using...

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is executed on the completion of the `alertPopup`, you will lose the reference to the `$window` element.

A possible solution is to keep a locally scoped reference to the `$window` object. And use that instead of trying to use $window directly.

```
let windowRef = $window;

alertPopup.then (function(res) {
      if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        windowRef.open('android_link_here', '_system')
      }
```

Comment: I used my method on android and it worked fine. This seems to only be issue with iOS.